# Python 3.2 W/ Pygame Crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Well, I was happy starting on Pygame with a bit of knowledge on python, But while i was following some starter tutorials i noticed that, At the moment of running my code the Pygame window didn't see to respond, so i put some "print" commands to see how far did it get, I noticed that it stopped on the Loop, Any ideas on how i can fix it? I will leave the code around here

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

print("First Fase")
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500)) 

pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

print("Second Fase")
x = 50
y =50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 7

print("Third Fase")

done = False
while not done:
 pygame.time.delay(100)

for event in pygame.event.get():
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
  done = True

if event.type == KEYDOWN:
 if event.key == K_ESC:
  done = True

pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
pygame.display.update()
print("NoErrors")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be `pygame.KEYDOWN` and `pygame.K_ESC` rather than `KEYDOWN` and `K_ESC`.

But fist of all you have to respect the **[Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=indent#indentation)**. In the following code the loops are not nested:

> ```
> done = False
> while not done:
>  pygame.time.delay(100)
>
> for event in pygame.event.get():
>  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>   done = True
> ```

The `for` loop is not in the `while`, it is a separate loop after the `while` loop.

You have to format your code like this:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

print("First Fase")
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500)) 

pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

print("Second Fase")
x = 50
y =50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 7

print("Third Fase")

done = False
while not done:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESC:
                done = True

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
    print("NoErrors")
```